# Compute the power of a function

Tags: functions

I have a function defined as follows:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} [x+1-(1-x)^{\alpha}] $$

where x belongs to the interval [0,1]. Furthermore $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = A$ where $A$ is a known constant. How can I determine the real power alpha knowing $A$? What can be the better approximation? Thanks for advance !!!

Comment: What does ** means?

Comment: Sorry. (1-x)**alpha means (1-x) power alpha.

Comment: but why f(1)=A?. It seems to me that f(1)=0.5 when $\alpha=0$, f(1)=1 when $\alpha>0$ and f(1) is undefined when $\alpha<0$

Comment: Actually f(0) = 0 and f(1) = A are the boundary conditions, where A is a positive constante belonging to [0,1] as alpha. And my purpose is to determine alpha. I was wondering maybe there can be a some approximation in order to extract alpha. The Taylor seris is not appropriate because when using it, alpha is no more in the function...I hope you understand my concern...

Answer (score 0):

Note that for definition of $f$:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
undefined, \space \alpha<0\\
1/2, \space \alpha=0\\
1, \space \alpha>0
\end{cases}
$$

knowing that $f(1)=1 \implies \alpha>1$, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

The family of functions $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} [x+1-(1-x)^{\alpha}] $ is represented below, on range $0\leq x\leq 1$ :

[image]

The point  $(x=1\:,\: f(1)=A=1)$ belongs to all curves with $\alpha> 0$. So, in case of $A=1$ , $\alpha$ is undetermined (positive).

If case of $0.5< A=f(1) < 1$ there is no exact solution. No curve crosses the point  $(x=1\:,\: A)$. The closest curve is with $\alpha=\epsilon>0\simeq 0.$

In case of $A=0.5$ , $\alpha=0.$

If case of $0< A=f(1) < 0.5$ there is no exact solution. No curve crosses the point  $(x=1\:,\: A)$. The closest curve is with $\alpha=-\epsilon<0\simeq 0.$

In addition :

( Case $\alpha>0$ )

When $x$ increases $f(x)$ increases. When $x$ comes close to $1$, it seems that $f(x)$ tends to a value $A$ lower than $1$. This is false because abruptly $f(x)$ increases very quickly and tends to $1$.

The curve never reaches the apparent limit $(1\:,\:A)$. So it is impossible to determine an exact value of $\alpha$ to satisfy what is expected.

But, one can consider the apparent (but false) limit $(1\:,\:A)$ and compute the corresponding value of $\alpha$ for the curve which seems going in direction of this point. With this approximate value of $\alpha$, the function $f(x)$ is an approximative function convenient for all $x$ until $x$ be not too close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanations, that's very kind and thoughtful of you, I really appreciate !!!

Comment: Please JJacquelin, as you pictured, all the functions are in 0 at x=0 but at different points at x=1. So is it possible to recover the alpha power if we know the value at x=1? What can be the approach because that is exactly my issue

Comment: Not exactly : The curves are not at different points at $x=1$. With all $\alpha>0$ , they are all at $(1,1)$. When $x$ increase  and tends to $1$, first $y$ increases and appears to tend to a value lower than $1$. But this is false. Abruptly $y$ increases and tends to $1$, not to a value lower than $1$. The curve becomes almost vertical (asymptotically vertical). On cannot distinguish this on the figure due to the width of the drawing. Indeed, it is not possible to recover an exact value for the $\alpha$ power.

Comment: Thanks again !!! I get the point

Comment: See the addition to the main answer about the question of approximate.